# Get byte[] in C# from char* in C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

In C# I have an data type `byte[]`, which I want to fill in using a C++ function which returns `char*`

The C++ function (in `ImageData.dll`)

```
char* pMemoryBuffer = NULL;
char* LoadData(const char *fileName)
{
    // processing pMemoryBuffer ...
    return pMemoryBuffer;  
}
```

Import native dll into C#:

```
    [DllImport(".\\Modules_Native\\ImageData.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadData")]
   private extern static byte[] LoadData(string fileName);
```

The `byte[]` data in C#

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256];
buffer = LoadData("D:\\myPic.tif");
```

Apparently it is not working yet, but it presents the idea of what I want to do. So I am wondering how to make this work, and what is the right way to do it. Thanks very much for your education.

Comment: It doesn't know how big the C# array must be.

Comment: See update in the thread. The size is initialized.

Comment: Can you improve your question by specifying how it's "not working"? I wasn't the down voter, but this may be the reason why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
// c++

    void LoadData(unsigned char* *pMemoryBuffer, const char *fileName)
    {
        // processing pMemoryBuffer ...
        *pMemoryBuffer = resutss;

    }
```

Import native dll into C#:

```
[DllImport(".\\Modules_Native\\ImageData.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadData")]
private extern static void LoadData(out IntPtr data, string fileName);
```

When the function returns data will point to the array and you can read the contents using the Marshal class. I guess you would [copy it to a new byte arra](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms146631.aspx)y.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256];
buffer = Marshal.Copy(LoadData(buffer ,"D:\\myPic.tif"), buffer , 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Your `Marshal.Copy` example is the right thing to do with a returned pointer.  If you can change the C code to make the output buffer an argument, then don't use `IntPtr` and `Marshal.Copy` at all.

Comment: What you have won't work, you need an `IntPtr` return value to make that `Marshal.Copy` snippet work.

Comment: If he's going to own the C++ code anyway, why not put the copying into C++? P/Invoke is gross enough without manually marshalling pointers in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but my gut says that you can't assign a char* to a byte array, just as you can't in C++ itself. You can either use an IntPtr in C# (probably not super useful), OR, you can pass C++ a byte[] buffer and a number of bytes to write. In other words, I think the following would work:

```
char* pMemoryBuffer = NULL;
int size = 0;
int seek = 0;
bool LoadData(const char* filename)
{
     // load filename
     // set seek = 0
     // set size to data size
}

int ReadData(char* buffer, int nBytesToRead)
{
    // nCopyBytes = min(nBytesToRead, size - seek)
    // copy nCopyBytes from pMemoryBuffer+seek to buffer
    // seek += nCopyBytes
    // return nCopyBytes
}
```

From C#, you'd use it like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256];
LoadData("foo.tif");

int bytesRead = ReadData(buffer, 256*256);
```

Sorry if you specifically want to avoid doing something like this.

Comment: The `out` keyword is inappropriate here, arrays are reference types and already get passed through p/invoke as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
[DllImport(@".\Modules_Native\ImageData.dll")]
private extern static IntPtr LoadData(string fileName);

byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256];
buffer = Marshal.Copy(LoadData("D:\\myPic.tif"), buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

However, it won't free the memory.  Hopefully the C(++) library frees it automatically during the next call, or else provides a deallocation function.

A better approach is to use a caller-allocated buffer, then you would just do:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256];
LoadData("D:\\myPic.tif", buffer);
```

For this, the C(++) code would need to be changed to

```
int LoadData(const char *fileName, char* pMemoryBuffer)
{
    // processing pMemoryBuffer ...
    return 1;  // if success
}
```

and the p/invoke declaration to

```
[DllImport(@".\Modules_Native\ImageData.dll")]
private extern static int LoadData(string fileName, byte[] buffer);
```

Comment: So is that my answer or what

Comment: @moez: No, it isn't.  You showed how to make an `out IntPtr` parameter, which I considered a bad idea, so I improved it into a new answer.  You didn't at all show how to use a caller-supplied buffer.  And you didn't mention the problem of getting the library to deallocate in the returned-buffer case.

Comment: @moez: Furthermore, everyone can see that my answer came before your edit...  So I think it's clear which direction the ideas are flowing (I won't accuse you of theft, I left you a correction in a comment because I was inviting you to use that, but you haven't done so correctly)

Comment: If he's going to own the C++ code anyway, why not put the copying into C++? P/Invoke is gross enough without manually marshalling pointers in C#.

Comment: @Patrick or avoid the copy entirely, which is what I already described as the better solution.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the second suggestion, which looks a bit like what I'm suggesting, but not as careful. What happens if the file is bigger than 64 kilobytes?

Comment: @Patrick if the exact size isn't known in advance, it should be passed as an additional parameter.