# Pass byte[] in C# to const char* in C++ and give output

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

got an issue on pass/recieve byte [] from/to C# code to/from C++ dll.
On execution it gives me "stack balancing" exeption, that means, values missmatch. Read a few articles before asking, and tried few... but still dont understand how i can solve it in that case:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void doProcessFile(const char* szSource, const char* szPassWord, char *strRet)
{
   //simple RC4 encryption. szSource - is byte[]
   //szPassWord- string. 
   //Function returns a byte[] as char*
   strRet = RC4EncryptTool::Decrypt(szSource, szPassWord);
}
```

and i am trying to interop them via:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "doProcessFile")]
public static extern void doProcessFile(byte[] szSource, string szPassWord, ref byte[] strRet);
```

but that's wont work.

Still experiment with it, and cant return byte[] anyways...

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "doProcessFile", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void doProcessFile(byte[] szSource, string szPassWord, ref byte[] strRet);
```

with variation of it via changing char *strRet to char* *strRet and char* strRet... nothing... it's always show me an empty array.

Reading those & tried : [Get byte[] in C# from char* in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454176/get-byte-in-c-sharp-from-char-in-c)
Not works in my case... byte[] buffer = new byte[256*256]; from that solution - is always empty in my case, C++ part of code not return value into C# (or even i cant read them).

Also i played with

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* doProcessFile(const char* szSource, const char* szPassWord)
{
   //simple RC4 encryption. szSource - is byte[]
   //szPassWord- string. 
   //Function returns a byte[] as char*
   return RC4EncryptTool::Decrypt(szSource, szPassWord);
}
```

And :

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "doProcessFile")]
public static extern byte[] doProcessFile(byte[] szSource, string szPassWord);
```

return me a error - "Unable set a retun value...".

Comment: It is the universal mishap for this diagnostic, the required CallingConvention is missing.  It is Cdecl.  That last argument looks exceedingly unhealthy, smells a lot like a dangling pointer bug.  It must be out IntPtr.  Crucial problems are that you have no idea how many bytes it returns and that you can't free the memory in case it doesn't dangle so odds that this can come to a good end at all are not high.

Comment: What is your calling convention? Maybe you need to add CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl

Comment: You first problem is the C++. It does nothing useful. strRet is a value parameter. The value you assign to it in your C++ function cannot be seen by the caller.

Comment: __cdecl (/Gd) CC is, Well, on other programm it's works perfectly. For example, i am using CreateContext(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr phRC) for __declspec(dllexport) bool CreateContext(HWND window, HGLRC *mGlrc) and it's working fine. But here - nope...

Comment: You know what I mean when I say that strRet is passed by value?

Comment: yep, it is. on test app, same function, but with simple strings "foo" C#, and assign "bar" on C++  - it's works, on ref value i am see the "bar". but no lucky to make them works with byte arrays...

Comment: The original function can't return anything. Before you go further you need to decide who is going to be responsive for allocating and deallocating the memory.

Comment: Can you explain? I tried alot of methods - no one work. It's throw error or return 0 only...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156856/discussion-between-happy-day-and-david-heffernan).